# Access to Checkboxes (NSButton) in a Controller View

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a View with 50 checkboxes (NSButton) in a OS X app. I need to access to each one in code, but the only way I find is to create 50 IBOutlet bindings. The IBOutlet collection is not available in OS X. How can I do?

Comment: Use the for loop.

Comment: But there is a way without 50 IBOutlets ?

Comment: This is the perfect case that you need programmatically create checkBoxes by loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to refer to the 50 checkboxes in your `ViewController` class (I'm assuming that you use view controllers) is by first retrieving the superview that contains each of the 50 checkboxes. This will be an `NSView` object. To distinguish between the checkboxes I recommend setting different tag values right in interface builder, but it really depends on what you want to do with the checkboxes. Then, you can use a loop to iterate through each of the subviews in this view, like this:

```
for i in view.subviews.filter({$0 as? NSButton != nil}).map({$0 as! NSButton}) {
    if i.bezelStyle == .regularSquare && !(i.cell as! NSButtonCell).imageDimsWhenDisabled {
        print(i.title)
    }
}
```

The `if` condition basically utilizes two properties of checkboxes to distinguish them from any other type of `NSButton`.

In this example, I simply printed the title of each checkbox. You can use a `switch` statement if you want to perform different tasks depending on which checkbox it is. The good thing is that with this method you can have infinitely many checkboxes. The iteration order is left to right, top to bottom.